XML to JSON postgresql
I found this code on the internet to convert xml to json
create or replace function xml_to_json(p_xml xml) returns jsonb as $$
declare
  result json;
  root text;
  childs jsonb;
  attr jsonb;
  txt text;
begin
  -- Get root element name
  select (xpath('name(/*)', p_xml))[1]::text into root;

  -- Process child nodes
  select json_agg(xml_to_json(z))
  from unnest(xpath('/'||root||'/*', p_xml)) with ordinality as c(z,i)
  into childs;

  -- Read attributes
  select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object((xpath('name(/'||root||'/@*['||i||'])', p_xml))[1]::text, v))
  from unnest(xpath('/'||root||'/@*', p_xml)::text[]) with ordinality as a(v,i) 
  into attr;

  -- Read text
  select (xpath('/'||root||'/text()', p_xml))[1]::text into txt;

  -- Build object
  result := jsonb_build_object(root, jsonb_build_object('attr', attr, 'text', txt, 'childs', childs));
  return result;
end $$ language plpgsql immutable;

it's giving me some unnecessary things like 'text', 'childs' in the json body itself
eg: IF the xml is as follows
<root>
    <a>a1</a>
    <b>
        <c>b1</c>
    </b>
</root>

The result look like
{
  "root": {
    "attr": null,
    "text": "\n    ",
    "childs": [
      {
        "a": {
          "attr": null,
          "text": "a1",
          "childs": null
        }
      },
      {
        "b": {
          "attr": null,
          "text": "\n        ",
          "childs": [
            {
              "c": {
                "attr": null,
                "text": "b1",
                "childs": null
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

But I want like this
{
  "root":  [
      {"a":  "a1"},
      {"b": [{"c": "b1"}]}
      
    ]
  
}

note that i'm using dbt macro and model
I tried removing from 'attr' ,'text' and  'childs'
result := jsonb_build_object(root, jsonb_build_object('attr', attr, 'text', txt, 'childs', childs));

it doesn't work that way

Well what do you want to do with attributes?

I don’t need attributes, just need more user friendly json

No off the shelf xml-to-json conversion library is going to give you exactly the JSON you want. Some like this one err on the side of being completely faithful to the XML data model, some try too hard to give you user-friendly JSON and lose information as a result. The only way to get exactly the JSON you want is to program it yourself (for example, using XSLT 3.0).
